# How to test axios requests parameters with sinon / chai

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai, sinon-chai

I am trying to test the parameters of an axios call using sinon / chai / mocha, to confirm the existence of certain parameters (and ideally that they are valid dates with moment).

Example code (in class **myclass**)

```
fetch() {
  axios.get('/test', { params: { start: '2018-01-01', end: '2018-01-30' } })
  .then(...);
}
```

Example test

```
describe('#testcase', () => {
  let spy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spy = sinon.spy(axios, "get");
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    spy.restore();
  });
  it('test fetch', () => {
    myclass.fetch();
    expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith('start', '2018-01-01');
    expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith('end', '2018-01-30');
  });
});
```

However, I have tried many options including matchers, `expect(axios.get)`... `expect(..).satisfy`, `getCall(0).args` and axios-mock-adapter, but I cannot figure out how to do this. What am I missing please?

Comment: sorry, example was bad as it did not call the function! I have updated it now - it is not the exact code as I cannot share that.

Comment: Could you let me know the `console.log(_spy.args)` just after `myclass.fetch()` in the testcode?

Comment: Have you tried passing it other parameters within your test and them expect them to beEqual? That's the only way I can imagine right now that you would test that

Comment: @YonggooNoh console.log(_spy.args) produces []

Comment: Turns out, the function I was testing was changed and so was not passing in the parameters.. so in this case, the test was (correctly) failing! I can confirm when using the above framework, `_spy.args` contains `[ [ '/test', { params: { start: '2018-01-01', end: '2018-01-30' } } }`. Using `_spy.args[0][1].params` can access it (though I am sure there is a better way!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster understood that he never called the function he wanted to test. Therefore there is nothing to debug or answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the unit test solution, you should use `sinon.stub`, not `sinon.spy`. Use `sinon.spy` will call the original method which means `axios.get` will send a real HTTP request.

E.g.
`index.ts`:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export class MyClass {
  fetch() {
    return axios.get("/test", {
      params: { start: "2018-01-01", end: "2018-01-30" }
    });
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from "./";
import sinon from "sinon";
import axios from "axios";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("MyClass", () => {
  describe("#fetch", () => {
    let stub;
    beforeEach(() => {
      stub = sinon.stub(axios, "get");
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      stub.restore();
    });
    it("should send request with correct parameters", () => {
      const myclass = new MyClass();
      myclass.fetch();
      expect(
        stub.calledWith("/test", {
          params: { start: "2018-01-01", end: "2018-01-30" }
        })
      ).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 MyClass
    #fetch
      ✓ should send request with correct parameters


  1 passing (8ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/50801243

Comment: this doesn't work when there's then in the axios call, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` which is not in the example. why would anyone do axios call without the response

Comment: @FadelTrivandiDipantara It depends if you actually do a petition to an API you aren't in the realm of unit testing anymore, you are doing an integration test.